# Memoized solution gives TLE while tabulated solution does not

Tags: c++, dynamic-programming, memoization

I am attempting the following question from Interviewbit:

> Given a m x n grid filled with non-negative numbers, find a path from top left to bottom right which minimizes the sum of all numbers along its path.
>
> NOTE: You can only move either down or right at any point in time.

I have written the following memoized solution:

```
int minPath(vector<vector<int> > &A, int i, int j, vector<vector<int> > &dp) {
if (dp[i][j] >= 0)
    return dp[i][j];
else if (i == A.size() - 1 && j == A[0].size() - 1)
    return dp[i][j] = A[i][j];
else if (i == A.size() - 1)
    return dp[i][j] = A[i][j] + minPath(A, i, j + 1, dp);
else if (j == A[0].size() - 1)
    return dp[i][j] = A[i][j] + minPath(A, i + 1, j, dp);
else
    return dp[i][j] = A[i][j] + min(minPath(A, i + 1, j, dp), minPath(A, i, j + 1, dp));
}

int Solution::minPathSum(vector<vector<int> > &A) {
if (A.size() == 0)
    return 0;

vector<vector<int> > dp(A.size(), vector<int>(A[0].size(), -1));
return minPath(A, 0, 0, dp);
}
```

This solution is giving a TLE during submission.

After a while I took a look at the editorial code, and they have followed the tabulation approach as follows:

```
int minPathSum(vector<vector<int> > &grid) {
        if (grid.size() == 0) return 0;
        int m = grid.size(), n = grid[0].size();
        int minPath[m + 1][n + 1];
        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
            minPath[i][0] = grid[i][0]; 
            if (i > 0) minPath[i][0] += minPath[i - 1][0];
            for (int j = 1; j < n; j++) {
                minPath[i][j] = grid[i][j] + minPath[i][j-1];
                if (i > 0) minPath[i][j] = min(minPath[i][j], grid[i][j] + minPath[i-1][j]);
            }
        }
    return minPath[m-1][n-1];
}
```

According to me, the time complexity of both the codes seem same, yet mine seems to be giving TLE. Where exactly am I going wrong?

Comment: Did the editorial code pass the oracle? It looks like you only need to remember the sums from the previous row. A 2d lookup seems excessive.

Comment: Yes, the editorial did not give a TLE.

Comment: No. I did not understand why you want me to pass (m, n) instead of (0, 0).

Comment: @KennyOstrom It can be converted in standard C++: https://wandbox.org/permlink/pwonyl6wZtzAboCk .

Comment: It looks like the memoization version makes a bunch of recursive function calls for absolutely no benefit. Normally, you'd expect c++ to handle tail recursion well and make those equivalent, but you have multiple recursion points inside the minPath logic, so it's not tail recursive. The only benefit of the memoization is doing an array lookup to avoiding an array lookup (basically). PS thanks for doing the easy but boring job of converting the VLA. I know I'm lazy but that wasn't my responsibility. :)

Comment: For a more interesting version of this problem, check out https://projecteuler.net/problem=67 This is my argument against having a 2d array. It's way more than you need to remember to solve this, if you only want to find the specific sum of the preferred path.

Comment: Incidentally, I couldn't easily bookmark it. Making the problem big enough to get enough time caused the recursive version to crash, presumably out of memory for the recursive stack (although I am just speculating there).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The test cases have negative numbers in the grid ( though they have explicitly mentioned non-negative numbers). So dp[i][j] can be negative but your function will never consider those values. Just used another vector to store the visited cell and it got accepted.

```
int minPath(vector<vector<int> > &A, int i, int j, vector<vector<int> > &dp,vector<vector<bool> > &vis)
{
    if (vis[i][j])
        return dp[i][j];
    vis[i][j] = 1;
    if (i == A.size() - 1 && j == A[0].size() - 1)
        return dp[i][j] = A[i][j];
    else if (i == A.size() - 1)
        return dp[i][j] = A[i][j] + minPath(A, i, j + 1, dp, vis);
    else if (j == A[0].size() - 1)
        return dp[i][j] = A[i][j] + minPath(A, i + 1, j, dp, vis);
    else
        return dp[i][j] = A[i][j] + min(minPath(A, i + 1, j, dp, vis), minPath(A, i, j + 1, dp, vis));
}

int Solution::minPathSum(vector<vector<int> > &A)
{
    if (A.size() == 0)
        return 0;

    vector<vector<int> > dp(A.size(), vector<int>(A[0].size(), -1));
    vector<vector<bool> > vis(A.size(), vector<bool>(A[0].size(), 0));
    return minPath(A, 0, 0, dp, vis);
}
```